# Using custom xml elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Given the following:

```
<p>This is a <fund id="12345">Test Fund</fund>. More text.</p>
```

How do I extract the text ("Test Fund") from the fund element?

I have tried the following:

```
$('fund').each(function(index) {

    alert($(this).text());

});
```

I can retrieve the id attribute as follows:

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

I have had no luck with text() html() etc.

**EDIT:**
Initially I had only tried IE8, But after test in firefox I discover it works with FF just fine. I then reviewed in IE dev tools and noticed that the Dom explorer was treating the opening tag as a stand-alone node, as well as doing this to the remaining text, and closing tag.

I found some info on using a custom namespace as follows:

```
<html xmlns:myns>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // Your code here
       $('myns:fund').each(function(index) {
            alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr("id"));
        });
     });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Sample paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a <myns:fund id="12345">Test Fund</fund>. More text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This fails also but renders correctly in the IE DOM explorer.

Comment: What kind of document are you working in? HTML?

Comment: You should update this to correct the } error, and note the IE8 issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me in Firefox 3.6 when I add the missing curly brace before the last parenthesis:

```
$('fund').each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

The above correctly prints `Test Fund`.

**EDIT:** I got it working in Internet Explorer 8 by calling [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the `<p>` element, applying [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to the result and calling [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on that:

```
$(document).ready(function(index) {
    alert($($("p").html()).text());
});
```

Comment: Since posting the question I did test in firefox and discovered in works fine (without the typo!). After opening the IE8 developer tools I noticed that The opening tag is being treated as a stand alone node and everything else as child nodes of the "<p>" element. Fixing IE is the goal. Any thoughts?

Comment: @HectorMac, same here. I'll try to find something.

Comment: It's really discouraging to look at the selector library's code and see that it selects by using the native `getElementsByTagName` which DOES work in IE8, but $('element') won't in this case. This may be a bug and may be noted in the sizzleJS bug page.

Comment: Yeah but that works for the wrong reasons... `<p>This is a<blah>now what?<level2>???</level2></blah> <fund id="12345">Test Fund</fund>. More text.</p>` There's something awkard with the sizzleJS library and IE8.

Comment: @user257493, I agree that's not a generic solution. I only tried to coerce good old IE into giving the proper result from the questioner's example :)

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the contents of the `<p>` tag as an HTML string, and passing that to the jQuery constructor, rather than trying to get the fund tag direct from the page:

```
var html = $("p").html();
alert($("<div>" + html + "</div>").find("fund").text());
```

**Edit**: you need to wrap the html inside a div (or other) element so jQuery doesn't get confused and think it's a selector. Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRggd/1/